# Issue with the final list print of obtaining prime divisors from a number

Tags: python

The only problem I am obtaining from doing this is that the program prints a list
that shows, say n = 11, the final outcome will print [2, 2, 3], when I just want [11]. That's how it is for most tests as well, it will have the numbers I need but extra ones as well.

```
    Base = 2
    divisors = [ ] 
    while n > 1:
        if n % Base == 0:
            divisors.append(Base)
            n = (n / Base)
        else:
            Base += 1 + Base % 2 
    return (divisors)
```

Comment: take a look at [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=data%20structures#sets) if your only problem is that you only need the unique values

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure that the divisor has not been used before in your `if` statement:

```
def prime_divisors(n):
    ns = 2
    divisors = [ ] 
    while n > 1:
        if n % ns == 0 and n not in divisors:
            divisors.append(ns)
            n = (n / ns)
        else:
            ns += 1 + ns % 2  # 2 -> 3, odd -> odd + 2
    return (divisors)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicate elements from your 'divisors' list,
you can use a function which is something like this.
Here list2 is another list which is initially empty.

```
for i in divisors:
    if i not in list2:
        list2.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing the logic where you divide `n` by `ns` to eliminate *all* factors of `ns`, rather than just one at a time. Then, since you never need to repeat an `ns` value at the top level, you can make the `else` block unconditional (this extra bit is not necessary, just nice):

```
def prime_divisors(n):
    ns = 2
    divisors = [] 
    while n > 1:
        if n % ns == 0:
            divisors.append(ns)
            while n % ns == 0:             # add this loop, to avoid duplicated factors
                n = (n / ns)
        ns += 1 + ns % 2  # 2 -> 3, odd -> odd + 2  # this can be run unconditionally
    return (divisors)
```

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what I  needed! Thank you